# Using object array with ngFor in Angular

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular7

I have this object array of countries and country codes.

```js
export class Countries {
  countryCode: object[] = [
    {
      name: 'Afghanistan',
      code: 'AF'
    },
    {
      name: 'land Islands',
      code: 'AX'
    }
  }

  CountryCode() {
    return this.countryCode;
  }
}
```

I initialize it like this

```
countryList: object[] = new Countries().countryCode;
```

But I can't seem to access the values `country.name` and `country.code` in the HTML.

**Errors are saying**

> Identifier 'name' is not defined

Here is my `ngFor`

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select
      id="country" class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let country of countryList;" 
      [value]="country.code">
      {{country.name}}
      </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: replace `[value]="country.code"` with `[ngValue]="country"` then selected value will be the country object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 - find selected value in dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000189/angular-4-find-selected-value-in-dropdown)

Comment: when I switch to ngValue, how do I get the name and code? Trying "country.name, country.code" shows an error

Comment: did you try to console.log(countryList) and see what is the output ?

Comment: countryList is an array of objects

Comment: Where do you initialize `countryList: object[] = new Countries().countryCode;`? also you have syntax error in `Countries` class

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.

```js
<div class="form-group">
                      <select
                        id="country" class="form-control" >
                        <option *ngFor="let country of countryList" 
                          [value]="country.code" 
                          [selected]="country.name == 'United States'">
                            {{country.name}}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
```

and I changed the country list to this

```
countryCode = [
    {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
    {name: 'land Islands', code: 'AX'}
 ];
```

from

```
countryCode: object[] = [
    {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
    {name: 'land Islands', code: 'AX'},
```